# How to find cell value where date is in column range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table with columns that represent "As Of Dates". In my example, I have a list of fruit, and the prices with different "as of dates".

Given a fruit name (text) and a date, how do I find the price of the fruit on that day?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
=INDEX(B3:D6,MATCH(A11,A3:A6,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:D2<=B11,0),0))
```

[image]